# How to resize a jScrollPane and have the scroll recognize the height of the content

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I inherited a project that uses a `jScrollPane` (using jQuery) that collapses and expands. When the scrollPane expands, we noticed that you can scroll way past the end of the content. Is there a way to tell jScrollPane that the height of the content is different upon resizing?

I tried to destroy/recreate the `jScrollpane` using `api.destroy`, but I only see it disappear, or is recreated with the original dimensions, which is not what I need.

I've created a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/tssparky/4StG2/10/

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a wrapper div for the jScrollPane, then set the fixed width on the wrapper. For the jScrollPane, I set the width to 100%. When I resized the wrapper div, I re-instantiated the jScrollPane and it reflowed the content. This gave me the results I desired.

```
$('#scrollpanecontainer').animate({
    'width': '700px',
    'left': '0'
    }, 100, function() {
        $('#scroll-pane').jScrollPane({ width: '100%', contentWidth: '100%', autoReinitialise: false});                 
});
```